# Single click edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can make an EditText have a onClick event so that on single click an action is done.

```
private void addListenerOnButton() {

        dateChanger = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_iWant);

        dateChanger.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }
```

this is not working as excepted....single click gives just the onscreen keypad but not the datepicker dialog which appears only if i double click

Comment: Is it necessary to use onClick() You can get this will onTouch() also..

Comment: what is the difference?? (I dont know actually)

Comment: dateChanger.setOnTouchListener and in onTouch() make condition  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){   showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

Comment: I think i have already given that answer check this link..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442470/android-hide-the-soft-keyboard-when-click-the-editview/10442514#10442514

Answer (score 11):

if we just add `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in edittext on layout page it should work in a singleclick on its onclicklistener. no need to handle onFocusChangeListener.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite**

I have an EditText that launches a dialog when the user either clicks it once or navigates to it with a trackball / directional pad.  I use this approach:

- Use an OnFocusChangeListener for gaining focus to open the dialog.
- Override dismissDialog() to clear the focus from the EditText when the user closes the dialog, preventing the user from entering text without the dialog (as far as I can tell)
  .

I have also tried this (however I now remember this method did respond to trackball movement):

- Use an OnClickListener for touch events.
- Set `setFocusable(false)` to prevent user input.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i chaged...this time it doesnt need a double click...but 1st click is not showing the dialog....next click show with just 1 click

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from an onClickListener to an OnFocusChangeListener.

```
private void addListenerOnButton() {

    dateChanger = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_iWant);

    dateChanger.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` is not meant for `singleClick`.

I mean you should not use Click Listener with it.
rather you can do like,

Use `onFocusChangeListener` which is also not 100% correct approach.

Best would be instead the `EditText` use one `TextView` write `onClick` of that and if needed give a background image to that TextView.

---

[image]

Comment: it will look good if you just use one background image..let me paste one image for example